# how to sum or calculate value in array use vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have data array in this

```
"item_tabel": [
  {
    "method": {
      "select_method": 6,
      
    },
    "innovation": {
      "select_innovation": 2,
    },
  }
],
```

how to calculate using sum ?

this my computed

```
subtotalRow() {
    return this.$store.state.item_tabel.map((item,i) => {
      return Number(item.method.select_method * item.innovation.select_innovation)
      //how to sum (item.method.select_method + item.innovation.select_innovation)
     });
 },
```

example in my table

```
No | method | inov | total
1  |    6   |  2   | (6+2 = 8) //calculate
2  |    2   |  2   |  4        //calculate
```

if using operator * works
and if using + doesn't work

thks

Comment: Add more detail to your question and expected result. Are you trying to achieve 6+2 or what? [ask]

Comment: yes right i want to make (6+2) not (6*2)
I tried sum extotal += not work

Comment: i update question bro hehe

Comment: If `+` gives you different results then your values might be strings. Did you try something like this `(+item.method.select_method + item.innovation.select_innovation)`

Answer (score 0):

#### If you really want to add the 6 and 2

Surely all you need to do is what you have written in your comment line?

```
subtotalRow() {
    return this.$store.state.item_tabel.map(
        (item,i) => (item.method.select_method + item.innovation.select_innovation)
    );
 },
```

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

#### This should work for you;

Since a callback function is required by Array.map() so the function body is supposed to be enclosed in braces '{}'

```
subtotalRow() {
    return this.$store.state.item_tabel.map(
        (item,i) => {item.method.select_method + item.innovation.select_innovation}
    );
 },
```

Comment: Please explain why this should work by editing your answer.

Comment: `Array.map` method expects a callback function that returns something.